# como hacer tooltips tipo tutorial javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="demo">
  <p><button data-tooltip="aqui accederas a la pagina si te encuentras registrado."> revisa tu pago</button> 
 </p>
</div>
<label><span tooltip="el label principal de la pg siempre aparecera para ayudarte" flow="left"> esto es un mensaje </span>
```

buenas tardes amigos tengo estos tooltip pero no se como lograr como mostrar el mensaje solo una vez al personal q se encuentra registrado ... la iadea es que aparesca o cuando se loguea o solamente cuando se registra .. podrian ayudarme por favor ?

no conozco del codigo que realiza la funcion

Comment: Los tooltips en html se agregar con el atributo title, a menos que estes usando alguna libreria que use tooltip. Ahora para que se muestre solo a los que estan registrados solo debes condicionarlo. Por ejemplo if(register) addAttr(tooltip).

Comment: disculpa la pregunta pero como funciona el if(register)

Comment: Eso lo haces con javascript o jquery, por ejemplo con jquery if(register) $('span').attr( 'title','Hola desde el title')

Comment: con eso para aparecer el titulo pero para q aparezca si el usuario es nuevo ? y desaparezca cuando el porfin entre o utilice la seccion que se solicito ? si me explico ?

Comment: Claro, eso depende de como accedes a los datos de sesion, porque en el caso que estes usando ajax tendras quizas un objecto data o algo asi, y de ahi solo es comparar. Por eso parti del If